# Graph conversion program required properties

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I use a relative preference system in a program I wrote. In this preference system, users are allowed to rate things using two preference values: A is greater than B OR A is much greater than B.

In order for my software to use this data, I currently represent the data using numerical values. In this way, the top rated item is given a value of 1, and the other items are given values depending on their relationship placement in the graph. Items greater than have values of 1 more than the next item, and items much greater have values of around 100 greater. So the following graph would be given the following values.

[image]

This is represented numerically in the following way: A (1), B (2), C (2), D (100), E (101).

I am looking for a software library through which I would be able to convert the graph preferences into numerical values and need to think about what this library needs to be able to do. I can see that I need to look out for circular paths in the graphs, which would definitely cause problems for preferences. But I wonder if there are any other important things that I need to look out for when converting the preferences?